# How to identify if the input string entered was two or more words in c++

Tags: c++

if I use the getline(cin, line) command for an input of the user. How can I tell how many words the user inserted. For example if the user typed "John Smith", how can I tell that their name has two words in it. I need to know this so I can use it in an if statement. Thankyou

Comment: if it has a space inbetween two letters it has more than one word. What did you try?

Comment: Parse the string.

Comment: I am unsure how I can tell if the input is longer than one word.

Comment: Which part of "if it has a space in between two letters it has more than one word" you did not understand?

Comment: I am creating a program where the user is able  to input their name. They can type their name as in many words as they want. So the input could be just John or John Smith Thomas. I need to know if the input is more than one word because later on in the program, if the user has a name more than one word long, I need to use an if statement on it for something.

Comment: Two ways I can think of: Look to see if there are spaces and use magic. Note that magic is highly unreliable. I've been trying for 30 years and haven't gotten it to work.

Comment: How would you do this if the name was written on a piece of paper? Now do the same thing using code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just count how many spaces do you have in a string.